# Issue with LaTeX code in "header-includes" in R Markdown file after R and RStudio upgrade

Tags: errors, header-footer, pdf, r, markdown

I use the following LaTeX code in the YAML of my R Markdown document (that produces, as output, a PDF):

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
- |
  ```{=latex} 
  \usepackage{microtype}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Times.otf}[
          BoldFont = TimesBold.otf]
  \usepackage{ragged2e}
  \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\scriptsize \justify}
  \usepackage{setspace}
  \usepackage{xcolor}
  \definecolor{very-light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
  \pagenumbering{gobble}
  \makeatletter
  \def\MT@is@composite#1#2\relax{%
    \ifx\\#2\\\else
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\MT@char\expandafter{\csname\expandafter
                      \string\csname\MT@encoding\endcsname
                      \MT@detokenize@n{#1}-\MT@detokenize@n{#2}\endcsname}%
      % 3 lines added:
      \ifx\UnicodeEncodingName\@undefined\else
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\MT@is@uni@comp\MT@char\iffontchar\else\fi\relax
      \fi
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\MT@is@letter\MT@char\relax\relax
      \ifnum\MT@char@ < \z@
        \ifMT@xunicode
          \edef\MT@char{\MT@exp@two@c\MT@strip@prefix\meaning\MT@char>\relax}%
            \expandafter\MT@exp@two@c\expandafter\MT@is@charx\expandafter
              \MT@char\MT@charxstring\relax\relax\relax\relax\relax
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  }
  % new:
  \def\MT@is@uni@comp#1\iffontchar#2\else#3\fi\relax{%
    \ifx\\#2\\\else\edef\MT@char{\iffontchar#2\fi}\fi
  }
  \makeatother
---
````

I found such code on a post on StackExchange (that unfortunately I can't find anymore), and it has worked since now. After an update of R and RStudio (and some R packages) I always get the following LaTeX error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

To be more precise, this error it's not due to some problems in the rest of my code in the document. I isolated the issue and found out that it is related to the piece of code inside the "header-includes:" section.

Do you have any suggestion to make my code work again?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. I changed the `header-includes` syntax and put the definition of the `microtype` macro, `MT@is@composite`, into a file called `mystyles.sty` and then just added `mystyles.sty` to the `header-includes` section. All those extra packages you are loading, and `\definecolor` and `\pagenumber` commands could be added to `mystyles.sty` if you wanted to do that. You might have to revert my change to `\setmainfont` since I changed this to what worked for me on a `Windows` system.

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
    latex_engine: xelatex
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{microtype}
  - \usepackage{fontspec}
  - \setmainfont{Times New Roman} #<- changed this
  - \usepackage{ragged2e}
  - \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\scriptsize\justify}
  - \usepackage{setspace}
  - \usepackage{xcolor}
  - \definecolor{very-light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
  - \pagenumbering{gobble}
  - \input{mystyles.sty}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

This is the content of `mystyles.sty`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\MT@is@composite#1#2\relax{%
  \ifx\\#2\\\else
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\MT@char\expandafter{\csname\expandafter
                    \string\csname\MT@encoding\endcsname
                    \MT@detokenize@n{#1}-\MT@detokenize@n{#2}\endcsname}%
% 3 lines added:
    \ifx\UnicodeEncodingName\@undefined\else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\MT@is@uni@comp\MT@char\iffontchar\else\fi\relax
    \fi
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\MT@is@letter\MT@char\relax\relax
    \ifnum\MT@char@ < \z@
      \ifMT@xunicode
        \edef\MT@char{\MT@exp@two@c\MT@strip@prefix\meaning\MT@char>\relax}%
          \expandafter\MT@exp@two@c\expandafter\MT@is@charx\expandafter
            \MT@char\MT@charxstring\relax\relax\relax\relax\relax
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
 }
% new:
 \def\MT@is@uni@comp#1\iffontchar#2\else#3\fi\relax{%
  \ifx\\#2\\\else\edef\MT@char{\iffontchar#2\fi}\fi
}
\makeatother
```

Your header content then appears in the preamble of the `.tex` files, just as intended. I added `keep_tex: true` to the `YAML` to keep the intermediate `.tex` file that is produced so that we can see what's going on in the header.

```
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\scriptsize\justify}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{very-light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\input{mystyles.sty}
```

[image]

If you are having trouble, make sure you `Clear Knitr Cache` before reexecuting the `.Rmd` file.

Comment: Hi Ross and thank you so much for your very comprehensive and useful answer! I marked it as correct because with a standalone Markdown file it works, but I forgot to specify that my .Rmd is embed inside a Shiny application. When I launch it, I got an error because the .sty file can't be found (even though I put it inside the same folder of the .otf files). Do you know how I can solve also this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you think I should create a separate comment for that request?

Comment: I don't use Shiny but my guidance would be: (a) do you really need that redefinition, (b) can you add it to the preamble in place of `mystyles.sty`. The only reason I used `mystyles.sty` was just to show that the header content can be included that way. Regarding another question, yes you could ask, but it is not really a LaTeX question. Maybe ask on StackOverflow?

Comment: You need to put `mystyles.sty` somewhere it can be found. You can nominate folders that are searched. On Windows, with MikTeX, this is done in the console under settings>directories.

Comment: Thank you Ross. I am still having issues in making the shiny app finding the file, but your point is correct. I don't know if I need that code anymore. I am trying to remember why I used it in the first place (I came back on this project after months). Do you have any hint that could make me remember what that code is for? I work on a Mac, so now I am gonna test the app also on Windows. Maybe that's why I added that code.

Comment: Hey Ross, everything works fine locally without adding that part of the code. Unfortunately, I am encountering problems when the application is deployed on shinyapps.io servers, because it seems that the unicode-math.sty package is not available. I've posted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63614521/latex-package-unicode-math-sty-not-found-when-application-is-deployed-on-shinyap). Thanks for your help!